# beautifulsoup, find text using re.compile

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Why is this not finding anything? I'm looking to extract the `id` out of this html.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
a="""
<html lang="en-US">
 <head>
  <title>
   Coverage
  </title>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
  <meta content="2017-07-12T08:12:00.0000000" name="created"/>
 </head>
 <body data-absolute-enabled="true" style="font-family:Calibri;font-size:11pt">
  <div id="div:{1586118a-0184-027e-07fc-99debbfc309f}{35}" style="position:absolute;left:1030px;top:449px;width:624px">
   <p id="p:{dd73b86c-408c-4068-a1e7-769ad024cf2e}{40}" style="margin-top:5.5pt;margin-bottom:5.5pt">
    {FB} 2 Facebook 465.8 /
    <span style="color:green">
     12
    </span>
    <span style="color:green">
     5
    </span>
    <span style="color:green">
     10
    </span>
    <span style="color:red">
     -3
    </span>
    / updated
   </p>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
"""
soup=BeautifulSoup(a,'html.parser')
ticker='{FB}'
target= soup.find('p', text = re.compile(ticker))
```

There is more than one `p` i just omitted the rest. I need the `text=` part

I've also tried the wildcards `(.*)` but still can get it to work.

I must get the `id` by ticker... i don't know anything else and the rest of the page is dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would get the `"id"` value for `<p>` tags which contains the text `"{FB}"`:

```
ticker='{FB}'
target= soup.find_all('p')
for items in target:
    check=items.text
    if '{FB}' in check:
        print (items.get("id"))
```

More compact way:

```
for elem in soup(text=re.compile(ticker)):
    print (elem.parent.get("id"))
```

Comment: there is more than one `p` i just omitted the rest, so i need the `text=` part

Comment: IMO very poor etiquette: someone gave you a perfectly good answer given what you requested. marking down for that is not good. And the answer is still appropriate, you just have to do multiple levels of 'find'.

Comment: i didn't vote it down... it's funny how you just assumed i voted it down and berated me for it....

Comment: @Sriram must I go through a loop? why doesn't the `text=` work? thought that would be easier since each `p` has a unique ticker

Comment: If you have a lot of `<p>` tags , you have do a `findAll()` that would fetch you all `<p>` tag structures. Looping it is the convenient option

Comment: what is the `text=` argument for then?

Comment: @Sriram Why are you using bs3 syntax? OP is using bs4.

Comment: @Sriram. Your code works. So I gave it an upvote... but still seeing if anybody can do it one line to avoid the loop. if not, it's the answer.

Comment: Updated the answer. Check it! gave a compact version , with `re.compile()` @jason